# How to add listView with scroll inside a Popup window in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

I am trying to make an android app which opens a popup window when clicked on a button. And, the popup window has four TextView with heading and 4 listView with options. However, I could not add listView inside a popup window. The popup window opens when clicking a button but when I add listView and its adapter and try to run it, the app crashes. I want the layout of PopUp window to be as one in news.xml file.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linear">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/news1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:text="@string/news" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.abina.popup;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;

import static android.view.Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Button news1;
    private PopupWindow popupWindow;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    ListView lst;
    String [] local = {"asdf","Sgadf","adfhtr","trdbfa"};
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //for listView 1
        lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,local);
        lst.setAdapter(adapter);
        lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,local[i],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        linearLayout  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        news1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.news1);
        news1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplication().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ViewGroup container  = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news,null);

                popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container,800,1300,true);
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(news1);
                container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**news.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ABEBC6">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="184dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/local" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:text="@string/national" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="184dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/sports1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginEnd="43dp"
            android:text="@string/sports2" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView3"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="184dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView4"
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="184dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Popup</string>
        <string name="news">Check Latest News!</string>
        <string name="local">Local News</string>
        <string name="national">National News</string>
        <string name="sports1">Sports One</string>
        <string name="sports2">Sports Two</string>


        <string-array name="local">
            <item>Star Ledger</item>
            <item>Ny Times</item>
            <item>The Record</item>
            <item>Trentorian</item>

        </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: A lot of posts are asking questions that could be answered if there is code, but there isn't. So make sure to check out [ask].

Comment: Thanks. I have added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your list doesn't exist in your activity_main layout. Rather it exists in popup window.

change your onCreate() method as the code below and it should work fine.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //for listView 1
    linearLayout  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
    news1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.news1);
    news1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplication().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup container  = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news,null);

            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container,800,1300,true);
            lst = container.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,local);
            lst.setAdapter(adapter);
            lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,local[i],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(news1);
            container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Hope this helps you.
Best regards,

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

In your action listener add this one:

```
   news1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());

            ArrayList<String> sortList = new ArrayList<>();
            sortList.add("A to Z");
            sortList.add("Z to A");
            sortList.add("Any");
            sortList.add("Test");

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                    sortList);
            ListView listViewSort = new ListView(getApplicationContext());
            listViewSort.setAdapter(adapter);

            // set on item selected
            listViewSort.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You select in popup menu" + adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });

            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
            popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            popupWindow.setContentView(listViewSort);
            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, 0, 0);

            });
        }
```

Comment: I could not use: / listViewSort.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener());   Could you put all the code in a single long code?

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. I have to add three more ListView in the popUp window. I could add a listView to the popUp window but could not position it in a unique position in a popUp Window. Could you help on it?

Answer (score 1):

Here example popup menu with two listviews and textviews:

```
     PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_element,
                (ViewGroup) view, false);
        //List first
        TextView nameOfList1 = layout.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        nameOfList1.setText("List one:");
        ListView mListView1 = layout.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final String[] data1 = {"Value from list 1", "Value from list 2", "Value from list 3", "Value from list 4",
                "Value from list 5", "Value from list 6"};
        mListView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data1));
        mListView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You select value from list one " + data1[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        //List second
        TextView nameOfList2 = layout.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        nameOfList2.setText("Select planet from list");
        ListView mListView2 = layout.findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        final String[] data2 = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
        mListView2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data2));
        mListView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You select plane  " + data2[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        popupWindow.setContentView(layout);
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, 0, 0);
```

And popup_element.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollojt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#f00"></ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
            android:background="#0f0"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @AkPasaf Please check this one, it should resolve your issue.